# Mootools (joomla) + jQuery + Firefox conflict: selector bug

Tags: jquery, firefox, joomla, mootools

This is a very specific - and bizarre - bug relating to these specific software versions:

- Joomla 1.5.23
- jQuery 1.7.2
- Mootools Upgrade (a Joomla plugin)
- Mootools 1.2.5
- Firefox 18.0.1

Note that the bug might be more widespread than that suggests; these are just the versions that I'm currently running.

In this combination,

```
jQuery('.st');
```

matches all three of the following elements:

```
<p class="test">one</p>
<p class="st">one</p>
<p class="stellar">one</p>
```

I've isolated the cause to the following from the mootools script:

```
Native.implement([Element, Document], {
    getElementsByClassName: function(className){
        MooTools.upgradeLog('1.1 > 1.2: Element.filterByTag is deprecated.');
        return this.getElements('.' + className);
    },

    getElementsBySelector: function(selector){
        MooTools.upgradeLog('1.1 > 1.2: Element.getElementsBySelector is deprecated. Use getElements()');
        return this.getElements(selector);
    }
});
```

Specifically, it's the return statement in `getElementsByClassName` that alters the native behaviour. I'm not sure why there's a problem only in Firefox and not, for example, Chrome.

I'm wary of just commenting out that code because I don't know a lot about this 'mootools upgrade' plugin, and what side-effects that will have. Is anyone familiar enough with enough of the above to be able to shed any light?

**UPDATE**

OK, after some debugging, I'm getting closer. The bug relates to the `Selectors.Filters.byClass` function which depends on the behaviour of `String.contains()`. Of course, mootools overrides that function - *BUT* the override only seems to take effect in Chrome. This also affects the `Element.hasClass` function which makes a similar call to `String.contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26 for the latest security

Upgrade jQuery to minimum 1.8.3. 1.9 (with migrate plugin if needed) if possible. Problem solved?

Comment: I'll answer your question in ... a while. (Upgrading jQuery is not a huge problem, upgrading Joomla on the other hand, is going to be problematic, to say the least. The code base I've inherited has been modified quite considerably, and I'm not overwhelmingly confident of an upgrade being successful.)

Comment: And, as you might see from my update, this looks very much like a mootools/mootools upgrade / Firefox issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Joomla plug-in - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18654
It will let you use jQuery with noConflict so you can use it alongside with Mootols in Joomla 1.5.
Good luck.

Comment: I'm already calling noConflict() - that simply frees up use of the `$` variable for other libraries (e.g. MooTools) to use. That is not the issue here - it's much more 'deep-seated' than that.